# Como usar <f:setPropertyActionListener> com Passthrough Elements no JSF 2?

Tags: java, html5, java-ee, jsf-2.2

estou utilizando elementos Passthrough em meu projeto JSF, e preciso fazer algo similar a isso:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{meuBean.acao()}" value="clique aqui">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{meuBean.objeto}" value="#{objetoLocal}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

mas usando elementos Passthrough para ter maior controle do meu frontend, como na tentativa abaixo:

```
<a href="#" jsf:action="#{meuBean.acao()}">clique aqui
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{meuBean.objeto}" value="#{objetoLocal}"/>
</a>
```

mas aparentemente isso não está funcionando, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: com.sun.faces.component.PassthroughElement
```

Alguém sabe como eu poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário estar usando algum prefixo para utilizar comandos do JSF.

Existe duas outras formas de gerar a tag `<a>` anchor, a primeira é com `<h:outputLink><\h:outputLink>` e a segunda é com `<h:link />`

Se o que você procura é os atributos, veja os equivalentes de cada tag e utilize, é provavel que tenha mais do que a própria tag `<a>`, a diferença é como será rendenizado.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_link_tag.htm

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_outputlink_tag.htm

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
    <a href="#" jsf:id="linkAction" jsf:action="#{meuBean.acao()}">clique aqui</a>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{meuBean.objeto}" value="#{objetoLocal}" for="linkAction"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Então, o erro que está acontecendo é simples, ele fala que a tag em html `<a>` não reconhece a tag `jsf:action`, pois essa é associada a um elemento do tipo `button` e não a um `ancor`.

Tente usar `<a type="bytton">` ou utilize o `<button jsf:action>` que é equivalente ao `h:commandButton` do jsf.